# Unexpected identifier on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to call a function with parameter on button click. In given code `SaveAmount(@item.Name)` function is getting called with parameter `@item`. Name but this throwing error i.e. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Here is my Html code:-

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.countries)
{
    <td><button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="cnt" onclick="saveAmount(@item.Name)">Update</button></td>
}
```

Here is my function:-

```
function saveAmount(btnId)
{
    alert("hiiii"+btnId);
}
```

Comment: I think id=cnt should be like id="cnt"

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `onclick="saveAmount('"+@item.Name+"')"`

Comment: Can you inspect "@item" object and check whether are u getting "Name". Use fire bug or check it in console log in server or client

Comment: yes.in SaveAmount() the value of name is getting passed properly i.e. United State in this case.and yes @item.Name is giving correct value in function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place id in  double quotes i.e id="cnt". try this

Comment: plz see the updated code.It was removed unfortunately.